# cloud commander in docker throws error "spawn wmic ENOENT"

Tags: windows, docker

now i try to see windows-Container's inside with cloud-commander.

dockerfile is this.

```
FROM stefanscherer/node-windows

RUN npm i cloudcmd -g

CMD cmd.exe cloudcmd

WORKDIR C:\\

EXPOSE 8000
```

Then the result geted from browser is this.

```
spawn wmic ENOENT
```

Do you see the reason? Or good way to manage files in windows-container with GUI? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `Cloud Commander` uses [win32](https://github.com/coderaiser/win32/blob/v4.0.1/lib/win.js) module which runs:

```
wmic logicaldisk get name
```

To get names of windows drives. [wmic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) is utility that provides a command-line interface for Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI).

The reason of using `wmic` instead of [native bindings](https://github.com/waitingsong/node-win32-api) is simplified installation, no need to build executables using c++ compilers.

Looks like docker image [stefanscherer/node-windows](https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanscherer/node-windows/) doesn’t have standard windows executables:

> The smallest possible Node.js image for Windows is based on Nano Server and only the node.exe included.

Try to use official Linux-based docker image [coderaiser/cloudcmd](https://hub.docker.com/r/coderaiser/cloudcmd/).

Anyways if you need windows-based docker image, you should install [wmic](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684) and add it to PATH, before running `Cloud Commander`.